# encryption in javascript and decryption in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#

methods to encrypt username and password which has to be done in client side and send encrypted data to server, in server the data has to be decrypted in asp.net. the methods other than https and ssl.

Comment: What's wrong with https?  Also, please edit your question to be a bit more coherent.  A bunch of sentence fragments tied together is not an acceptable question (in my opinion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save yourself months of pain and use HTTPS. Unless you are a security expert, what you are asking is extremely unwise and is almost guaranteed to have security holes.

Comment: *Years* if he had to maintain the hacky setup :).

Answer (score 0):

If you only *check* login and password, you can use some hash functions like md5 or sha1 or else.